# jQuery.Rule plugin how to change existing style?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

In a file called styles.css I have a css rule similar to this

```
#id.class1.class2 {
    top: 10px;
}
```

and I use a link tag in a file called index.html to use it. After reading through the jQuery.Rule [api](http://flesler.webs.com/jQuery.Rule/API.txt)I tried to change the value of top with attr

```
$.rule('#id.class1.class2','style').attr('top','20px')
```

but nothing happens other than an f.rule object being returned. How can I change the css rule? Would it be easier to do this without jQuery.rule?

Comment: What's the point of a `#id.class1.class2` selector? since `#id` is supposed to be unique within the document, you should be able to just use `#id`.

Comment: because I want the css for that element to change when I add class2 to it. i.e. #id.class1 would be blue but #id.class1.class2 would be green

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the plugin, but `.attr()` usually looks something like this:

```
$('#id.class1.class2').attr('style','top:20px;');
```

[API doc. for .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

you could also try something like:

```
$('#id').css('top','20px');
```

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work. I think I may just go with adding a style tag to the head and changing the text everytime I want to update it